# Adding depth of field to Individual passes i.e Emission, Ambient Occlusion, mist, etc?

Tags: cycles-render-engine, eevee-render-engine, compositing-nodes, depth-of-field, settings

So I've been using the built in depth of field in blender more on my renders, however I notice this isn't transferred over to any of my passes, making it harder for me in my compositing stage. I've been looking for solutions or workflows for a few weeks but no luck. Is there a certain composting setup to achieve this, or a setting ? Any input on this would be very helpful and useful. Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

You can create your compositing tree and add your DOP effect at the end so you can choose what is sharp or blurry using the Mist pass and a Defocus node. You can choose your plane of focus using a Color ramp like this:

[image]